# Magento: Showing only simple products on checkout success page

Tags: magento

I've successfully displayed the products ordered on checkout success (success.phtml), but the problem is it's displaying the configurable *and* the associated simple product when I want to display only the simple one. I tried doing it as below but then it doesn't display anything. I can't even use typeof on $item so obviously doing something wrong. 
Would someone kindly take a look at my code and give me a hint as to how to get it working properly? Cheers.

```
<?php $order_id = 

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id); 
foreach ($order_details->getAllItems() as $item): ?>
<?php if ($item->getParentProductId()): ?>
<h4> <?php echo $item->getName(); ?> </h4>
<br />
<h4>Quantity: <?php echo round($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0); ?> </h4>
<br />
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" class="media-object img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel($item, 'small_image'); ?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically look at the type of the product object, this is untested so I don't know if it will work, but you get the idea.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order_details = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id); 
foreach ($order_details->getAllItems() as $item): ?>
<?php if ($item->getProduct()->getTypeID() == 'simple'): ?>
<h4> <?php echo $item->getName(); ?> </h4>
<br />
<h4>Quantity: <?php echo round($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0); ?> </h4>
<br />
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" class="media-object img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $this->getImageLabel($item, 'small_image'); ?>"/>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, still doesn't display anything. Thanks for having a go at it though!

Comment: sorry editted the if statement, maybe your code wasn't going into the if statement because of what it returns

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I tried everything EXCEPT getTypeId.